# Excel VBA: How to find last row of a worksheet containing actual data

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I know how to find the last row of my worksheet that has any type of data or values

```
Dim lastRow As Integer
   With ActiveSheet
       lastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   End With
```

**Question:** How do I identify that last row with actual data, in otherwords the last row that doesn't have "#N/A" value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub hjksdf()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
       lastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "B").Text <> "#N/A" Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    lastRow = i
    MsgBox i
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

Here are ways to find the **last** *Z* and the **first** *Z*:

```
Sub FindLastZ()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
       lastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "B").Text = "Z" Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    lastRow = i
    MsgBox i

End Sub

Sub FindFirstZ()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
       lastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If Cells(i, "B").Text = "Z" Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    lastRow = i
    MsgBox i

End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent, that gets me exactly what I need.  I will then use this lastRow value to handle all of my page setup, printing and formatting. I'll probably rename the macro to something a bit more relevant though ;-)

Comment: @dasMetzger  Please remember to use **Long**

Comment: I saw that in another thread. What's the reason for using long here instead of integer or even range

Comment: @dasMetzger Integer is good to **32767**.  Long is good to **2147483647**